# Inkscape SVG to Android Vector

Tags: android, svg, vector, inkscape

I am making my first Android app, and I am trying to make my own icons.
I have manage to create the icons in Inkscape, but I didn't manage to convert the SVG from Inkscape to Android vector.

I have tried any thing, with no succeeded.

1. Kind of "[mode](https://inkscape.org/%7Eowenfromcanada/%E2%98%85androidvector)" for Inkscape that gives the xml for android - crushed.
2. Convert the objects to path (in Inkscape) - nothing.
3. Online [convertor](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter) - not working.
4. Android Studio's built-in "SVG to vector" convertor ( [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)).
5. A LOT of posts that I cant remember them all - but this is [one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70479/inkscape-export-xml-for-android-drawable-resource-directory) of them.

Is there any way to convert the SVG output from Inkscape to Android vector?

Comment: Probably. For the extension, I would suggest to report the bug to its author or to try to find someone else to update and fix it for Inkscape 1.0 (or to use it with an older Inkscape version). For the online convertor, check the list of incompatible features, and report a bug if needed. We don't know what result you got for the Android Studio thing (please add information). If you share the file, you would allow people to help fix things in it.

Comment: I think the problem was that android is not compatible with redial grediant. and with the linear grediant link.

Comment: This pull request fix crush in AndroidVector plugin for inkscape:
https://github.com/owenfromcanada/inkscape-androidvector/pull/4/commits/ede63de07210ad0453fac0e2ebbae140587a499d

Just replace androidvector.py in extension.